# Meaning of digits of HTTP responses in PyCharm terminal

Tags: http, terminal, pycharm

What do the numbers at the end of queries mean, like 459, 186, 459, etc?

```
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:00] "GET /topics/ HTTP/1.1" 200 459
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 186
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:02] "GET /topics/ HTTP/1.1" 200 459
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:04] "GET /topics/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2002
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 186
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:09] "GET /topics/ HTTP/1.1" 200 459
[13/Nov/2020 16:35:10] "GET /topics/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1850
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a response size in bytes from server

Answer (score 0):

It represents the length of content returned by that particular API.